# Copy Azure Blob with metdata from One storage account to another using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have to move Azure blobs stored in a container to another container. The problem is when the blobs are moved from the source to the destination, the properties are lost. I need to preserve the blob property which are required in downstream application. How can I achieve this.

Comment: are you moving files accross the same storage account butdifferent container ? Do you have to use data factory ? How many file do you need to move ? you can simply use az copy to do this. there are a lot of way of doing it

Comment: i am moving the files across different subscription and different container, thus different storage. I am open with any approach, but I need to do a lookup from sql server to get the list of blobs that i need to copy. i have lots of blobsto move

Comment: The simplest way would to use a logic app: you can copy blob + properties. you can also call SQL server. How big are your file ?

Comment: The files are of very small size. In Kb. The files are organized in this way. Name\year\month\day\actual blob. I have to get the Name, which is stored in a SQL table. Based on the Name, I have to iterate in the container and pull all the files. What approach shall I use

Comment: yeah logic app should work

Comment: Can you suggest the approach that I should take

Comment: how do you want your logic app to be triggered ? timer / http ? inside your logic app, call sql server to get the files you want to copy. Then iterate through the files and copy from one blob storage to another one

Comment: we actually are using a web job to achieve this.